# How to correct eclipse tomcat server error

Tags: java, eclipse

I got following error when I tried to run a project on eclipse. Can someone please explain what can be done to resolve it.

```
Could not publish server configuration for Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost.
Multiple Contexts have a path of "/CityHotel".
Multiple Contexts have a path of "/OOPEmployeeWebApp".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly you have a context configured in Eclipse and a WAR file deployed in the Tomcat webapps directory, both with the same name.

Comment: This solved it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

check your tomcat folder and `/conf and server.xml`, and remove the duplicated contexts

Answer (score 0):

It should be a configuration problem, might be you need some server specific configs you didnt set, thus it is throwing the error.

It could also be an actual duplication error, in which case check all class paths for duplications.